# Cannot find texlive-lang-dutch (and many others) in apt

Tags: texlive, languages, ubuntu

I am trying to install the 'texlive-lang-dutch' package on my Kubuntu machine. I tried:

```
sudo apt install texlive-lang-dutch
```

But this doesn't work. Obviously, the package is not available:

```
Unable to locate package texlive-lang-dutch
```

Indeed, I checked which language packages are available:

```
texlive-lang-african      texlive-lang-chinese      texlive-lang-czechslovak  texlive-lang-french       texlive-lang-indic        texlive-lang-korean       texlive-lang-portuguese   
texlive-lang-all          texlive-lang-cjk          texlive-lang-english      texlive-lang-german       texlive-lang-italian      texlive-lang-other        texlive-lang-spanish      
texlive-lang-arabic       texlive-lang-cyrillic     texlive-lang-european     texlive-lang-greek        texlive-lang-japanese     texlive-lang-polish
```

It is obvious that many language packages are missing, not just dutch. I tried searching for a solution. So far I have tried

```
sudo apt clean all
sudo apt upgrade
```

and

```
sudo apt clean all
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

This doesn't help. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: You can install `texlive-lang-all`... Or just `texlive-full`!

Comment: Yes, I could do this but it is not really a solution if I want only one or few languages

Comment: The `texlive-latex-base` package provides `babel` with dutch support.

Answer (score 5):

Try installing `texlive-lang-european`. (Take a look at [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/texlive-lang-dutch))

Edit: Thanks to [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) for clarifying that you don't need to install `texlive-lang-dutch` afterwards

Comment: After a long search, this is the way to go! Thanks, 'sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-european' did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

i had to check my textlive packages online repository and search for
"french" package by typing "french" (ctl+f)

rep: ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2017/tlnet-final/archive/
package found: babel-french

line command: tlmgr install babel-french

It worked for me and it should help somehow!

Comment: Note that the question is about Ubuntu/Debian packages installed with `apt`, which are different from `tlmgr` (TeX Live package manager) packages that you mention in your answer.